# is there any way to Update ASRP Property at UGC node?

Tags: aem

there is a tool to delete the UGC node in SRP, 
but i was looking for a way to update the Property of blog Post at UGC Node in ASRP,
i knew we can do it from UI it self, But assume there are 1000 Blog posts, 
and we need to Add a update a specific Property in UGC node.

Let me know if any one have idea.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found solution after raising ticket with Adobe day care and they have shared solution via Github,
check below link 
https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/aem-communities-srp-tools